# Error to execute a Robot Framework/Selenium test case on Firefox - Connection refused (os error 111)

Tags: docker, selenium, firefox, robotframework, geckodriver

For some reason, I'm not able to execute a Robot Framework test case in a docker container using Firefox. I've already tried many different versions for the geckodriver, but the result is always the same: "TimeoutException: Message: Connection refused (os error 111)". Obs.: with Chrome (no-sanbox), it works fine.

Any clue about how to solve it?

```
Firefox version: 78.9.0esr
Geckodriver version: 0.29.0
Platform: Linux 3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64
```

Here the Robot Framework keyword:

```
Open Firefox
    [Arguments]    ${URL}
    ${firefox options} =     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].firefox.webdriver.Options()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${firefox options}   add_argument     -headless
    Create Webdriver    Firefox    firefox_options=${firefox options} 
    Set Window Size  1024  768
    Go To    ${URL}
```

And here the details in the RF log:

```
13:48:00.234    INFO    Creating an instance of the Firefox WebDriver.  
13:48:00.247    DEBUG   POST http://127.0.0.1:37520/session {"capabilities": {"firstMatch": [{}], "alwaysMatch": {"browserName": "firefox", "acceptInsecureCerts": true, "moz:firefoxOptions": {"args": ["-headless", "-foreground"]}}}, "desiredCapabilities": {"browserName": "firefox", "acceptInsecureCerts": true, "marionette": true, "moz:firefoxOptions": {"args": ["-headless", "-foreground"]}}}  
13:48:00.248    DEBUG   Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1:37520   
13:49:00.280    DEBUG   http://127.0.0.1:37520 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 500 91  
13:49:00.281    DEBUG   Finished Request    
13:49:00.284    FAIL    TimeoutException: Message: Connection refused (os error 111)
13:49:00.284    DEBUG   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/SeleniumLibrary/__init__.py", line 492, in run_keyword
    return DynamicCore.run_keyword(self, name, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/robotlibcore.py", line 103, in run_keyword
    return self.keywords[name](*args, **(kwargs or {}))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/SeleniumLibrary/keywords/browsermanagement.py", line 391, in create_webdriver
    driver = creation_func(**init_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

==============

```
Dockerfile

FROM maven2.it.volvo.net:18468/gdsp-inbound-agent:4.6-1

LABEL Maintainer="RWT"
LABEL Description="This is a slave agent to be used for integration and performance tests"

#=========
# Firefox
#=========
RUN apt-get update -qqy \
    && apt-get install -qqy \
    firefox-esr

#============
# GeckoDriver
#============
RUN wget -q "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.29.0/geckodriver-v0.29.0-linux64.tar.gz" -O /tmp/geckodriver.tgz \
    && tar zxf /tmp/geckodriver.tgz -C /usr/bin/ \
    && rm /tmp/geckodriver.tgz

# Put geckodriver in the path
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/geckodriver \
    && chmod 777 /usr/bin/geckodriver \
    && chmod +x /usr/bin/geckodriver

#============
# Chrome
#============
# chrome installation
RUN apt-get update
RUN curl https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -o /chrome.deb
RUN dpkg -i /chrome.deb || apt-get install -yf
RUN rm /chrome.deb 

#============
# Chrome web driver
#============
#chrome driver installation
RUN wget -q "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/chromedriver_linux64.zip" -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /usr/bin/ \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip

# python installation
RUN apt install -y python3-pip
RUN apt-get install python3-psycopg2 -yf 

# when building this image, you must manually copy the requirements.txt from ../API/Dependencies into the Dockerfile dir
COPY ./requirements.txt .
# install robot dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 4444
EXPOSE 2828
EXPOSE 40000-60000

RUN mkdir /.local && chmod 777 /.local
RUN mkdir /tmp/firefox && chmod 777 /tmp/firefox
```

Comment: Why do not you use the `Open Browser` keyword? You can run headless much easier with that and you can still add any Firefox option or argument.

Comment: I already tried it, no success =/

Comment: Can you paste your Dockerfile?

Comment: Hello, dockerfile added